# How to parse non-standard date / time in Go ? Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit

Tags: time, go

I'm trying to parse dates received in email headers. Recently I've got stuck on this one `Thu, 7 Aug 2014 14:03:05 +0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)`. What kind of layout am I supposed to use ? `Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700 (MST)` doesn't do the trick.

I've also tried the workaround below but it still doesn't work. I'm not sure why Mitt... is not being replaced.

```
if strings.Contains(d, "Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit") {
    d = strings.Replace(d, "Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit", "CEST", 1)
}
```

Comment: Seems to work : http://play.golang.org/p/-_NOXHpLvq

Comment: I think is an encoding issue or something. In the logs I actually have this logged as Mitteleurop�ische Sommerzeit . ANy idea how to fix this encoding issue ?

Comment: nevermind...`x := strings.Split(d, "(Mitteleuro")
  d = x[0]
  d = strings.Replace(d, "Mitteleuro", "CEST)", 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit` part is indeed not recognized by the `time` package. But it works perfectly when you replace it by `CEST`:

```
var d = "Thu, 7 Aug 2014 14:03:05 +0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)"
_, err := time.Parse("Mon, _2 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700 (MST)", d)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err) // There is indeed an error
}

d = strings.Replace(d, "Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit", "CEST", 1)
t, err := time.Parse("Mon, _2 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700 (MST)", d)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err) // No error this time
}
fmt.Println(t) // 2014-08-07 14:03:05 +0200 CEST
```

On [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/cXgcUQuXN4).

Do not forget to write `_2` instead of `2` in your layout, so that days with two figures can be parsed too.

Answer (score 1):

It is redundant to try and parse the parenthesized timezone name when you already know the correct numeric offset:

```
Thu, 7 Aug 2014 14:03:05 +0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)
```

is equally specific as

```
Thu, 7 Aug 2014 14:03:05 +0200
```

The only additional information you get out of the first representation is that it was summer when the email was sent and that the region from which the email's author comes from is central Europe (literally "central Europe summertime").

This will not, however, affect the `time.Time` value's representation in contrast to the second string because the daylight saving adjustment is already reflected in the numerical timezone representation `+0200` which would be `+0100` during winter.

In other words, in this case you can ignore the spelled-out timezone specification.